# Dealing with leptokurtosis, should I be worried?

Tags: r, residuals, statsmodels, qq-plot

I modeled a mixed model with the lmer library in Rstudio and my residues don't seem normal, with a Shapiro-Wilk test p-value <0.0001 and a QQ-plot that looks heavy tailed. I then plotted the residues in an histogram with the normal distribution that I should be getting and it confirms that it is indeed heavy tailed/leptokurtic.

I'm not sure what the ramifications of this are, I understand there will be a risk of type 2 error because of the outliers that cause this kurtosis, but will there be some sort of problem with the calculation of the fixed effects?

TL;DR: Is leptokurtosis a problem that I should try to fix or can I ignore it and take the predictors at face value?

[image: Plots]

Comment: Median regression is an option.  But scientifically, I would think the interest would be more on modeling the entire data generating process, rather than on just the conditional location. Thus, you might consider a mixture model, because the residuals look like they come from a mixture of normals.